# How can I enable a Gtk.SpinButton in a Gtk.FileChooser?

Tags: python, gtk

In my application, I want to make an save mechanism for images.
For this, I'm using a `Gtk.FileChooserDialog` to select the location of the new file. It is working fine, but I'd also like to be able to select the size of the image (width and height).

I use `Gtk.Spinbutton` for this and adding them to the `content_area` of my dialog, then I force to show it.
The widget is showing fine, but I can't interact like to a normal `Gtk.Spinbutton`: I can't change the value by scrolling nor by clicking on the increment / decrement buttons.

I can still changing the value by typing into the entry.

code showing the issue:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.connect("destroy", self.on_destroy)

        self.set_icon_name("applications-development")
        self.show_all()

        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
            transient_for = self,
            buttons = (
                Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, Gtk.ResponseType.OK
            )
        )

        spinbutton = Gtk.SpinButton()
        spinbutton.set_range(0, 10)
        spinbutton.set_value(5)
        spinbutton.show()

        dialog.get_content_area().pack_start(spinbutton, True, False, 0)

        dialog.run()
        dialog.hide()

    def on_destroy(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Window()
Gtk.main()
```

Both in python version `2.7.6` and `3.4.3` this bug occurs.

Comment: I can't reproduce with GTK+ 3.16. What version of GTK+ are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps for the two buttons are not specified. So you can either do:

```
spinbutton = Gtk.SpinButton()
spinbutton.set_range(0, 10)
spinbutton.set_increments(1, -1)
spinbutton.set_value(5)
spinbutton.show()
```

or:

```
spinbutton = Gtk.SpinButton.new_with_range(0, 10, 1)
spinbutton.set_value(5)
spinbutton.show()
```